# What percentage of genome do slugs and scallops have in common?

Tags: genetics, evolution, dna, genomics, molluscs

We can know genetic distance of thousands of species. The OTT tree of life gives genetic distance for nearly all species. Is there a resource to compare the genomes of any sequenced animals to know the percentage of DNA they have in common? I wanted to know for slugs and scallops.

Comment: The question is actually not that easy. Many parts of the genome will fail to align and many aligned part will differ in length. So the question "What percentage of the genome species A and species B have in common?" is actually quite undefined.